# Android textview's text size is not scaled according to device

Tags: android

I have an application and textview's text size looks very fine on 4.7 inch device(screen density 2.0). but on 7 inch device (Screen Density 1.0) it's size will not increase according to the device size and looks very bad. any help?

please find the code.
`

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_selector"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip">   
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/iconImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/repairText"   
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Ashish"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#525c69"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/repairInfo" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Ashish"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#7f8d9f"/>

</LinearLayout>
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/statusImage" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

```
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="1dip"
         android:background="@drawable/horizontaldivider"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"

        />
```

`

Comment: Did u give size as match_parent??

Comment: post your layout code, how you are defining it.

Comment: use the unit "sp" for font size

Answer (score 0):

For Fonts to scale accordingly, you have to use `sp` as the unit for your text size values. This will make the font size depend on the System Preference and the device Resolution.

If this still is not enough, you could define different text sizes for different devices via qualifiers and resource Dimension files. Add a file named e.g. `dimen.xml` to `/values-large/` for large-scale devices, and anotherone to `/values-small/` etc.

You can then reference These values and Android will automatically use the Dimension that fits the current device.

You can find more Information on Dimension resources [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).